# Migrating data to Postgres from Mysql with Django - how do I migrate generic table data, not model specific?

Tags: django, migration

1. `python manage.py dumpdata modelName > file.json`.
2. created an empty database for a user `meder` on postgres
3. modified pga_hb.conf so that `meder` can use the database
4. changed the settings in `settings.py`
5. python manage.py syncdb ( I didnt create a su )
6. attempting to `loaddata file.json` but it complains that the superuser isn't there or doesn't match up...

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "manage.py", line 11, in 
       execute_manager(settings)
     File "/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 438, in execute_manager
       utility.execute()
     File "/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 379, in execute
       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
     File "/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
     File "/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
     File "/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 219, in handle
       transaction.commit(using=using)
     File "/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 199, in commit
       connection._commit()
     File "/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/**init**.py", line 32, in _commit
       return self.connection.commit()
   psycopg2.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "bugs_bug" violates foreign key constraint "poster_id_refs_id_89e0243f"
   DETAIL:  Key (poster_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user".

Was I not supposed to syncdb? Was I supposed to dumpdata for the generic tables? I still have the db all intact in MySQL but would appreciate any direction.

**SIDENOTE**: I do have `south` installed. I did the `--initial` command a couple days ago. Perhaps I could use south as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to run:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > file.json.
```

This will dump data from all tables(Models).

Running `python manage.py dumpdata myapp.modelName > file.json.` will only dump data for model modelName in app myapp.

You can also try, this if you only want to dump data for model modelName:

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth myapp.MyModel > file.json
```

This way data with Users will also dumped.

Comment: perfect, I thought I had to do that but some example syntax just showed how to dump the model only so I didn't think it was possible.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural > file.json.
```

More here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---natural

Comment: The `--natural` option will tell Django to use natural keys if available.

Answer (score 0):

long time ago after excruciating export/import jsons pains I end up using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-mysql2pgsql